# Initialize function error while using Twitter Bootstrap + Codeigniter + jquery pluguin

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeigniter + TwitterBootstrap +jquery

Whenever i add any javascript plugin be it Uploadify(flash version), ratty, Tagit, tagsManager

The initialize function always throw this kind of error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tagsManager' 
(anonymous function) 
c 
p.fireWith 
b.extend.ready 
H
```

Kindly advise as to what i am doing wrong!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I checked and made sure that tagsManager.js is loaded properly, and I still get this error.  Did you need to include something else?

Comment: Sorry for late reply no i did not add anything else, The problem was the tags manager script was not loading due to some reason. Make sure that you are loading tagsmanager.js after jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means the browser couldn't find method `tagsManager` and that means your script has not been loaded properly... make sure you load all your required js like jquery or tagsmanager scripts in head.... before it is called...